Springboot traceId and spanId not printing in logs
I have a springboot project v3.2.3 and java 17. I am not able to print the traceId and spanId after adding micrometer dependency.
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

Earlier I was using spring 2.7.2 with java 11 using
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>

and I was able to see the traceIds in the logs.
Log pattern in logback-spring.xml
[${springAppName}] %d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p [%X{X-B3-RequestId}] [%X{traceId:-}] [%X{traceId}] [%X{spanId:-}] [%X{spanId}] [%C{0}] - %msg%n"

Can someone help?
Expected to see traceId and spanId in logs after migrating to micrometer from sleuth, but saw empty strings.
